# IE old border displays on top of class-based border

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, border, render, css-tables

I'm having a problem where in IE9, 10 and 11 this happens.

What I am essentially doing is having all td's in the table have a border 1px solid gray and I am doing a 7px green border around some of the cells.

It looks correct in browsers other than IE, in IE it does this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q93mk7ox7jy9xpq/Screenshot%202014-07-24%2015.23.18.png

it shows BOTH the gray border AND the green one, with the gray one on top bleeding through.

This is the correct result from Chrome:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6u0o153917b3lm/Screenshot%202014-07-24%2015.25.18.png

Here is my CSS:

---

```
table.wirewatch2 td {
    background-color: #e7f9bf;
    border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
}
table.wirewatch2 tr:first-child > td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    border-top: 7px solid green;
}
table.wirewatch2 tr:last-child > td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 7px solid green;
}
table.wirewatch2 td:first-child {
    background-color: #b9d1f4;
}
table.wirewatch2 td:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: 7px solid green;
}
table.wirewatch2 td:nth-last-child(2) {
    border-right: 7px solid green;
}
table.wirewatch2 td:last-child {
    background-color: #d7b5b6;
}
```

All this is reported to work in IE9+ in w3schools and caniuse.com .

Now my project manager was doing this via a bunch of COL tags with inline styles before, and it had the same behavior (proper on anything other than IE), which leads me to believe it's not a IE feature support issue but a rendering engine issue.

Anyone ever come up against this and know how to fix it?

Comment: Sometimes you need to fiddle with things in IE because, you know, it sucks. This is totally new too me. Have you tried border-collapse? That might give a result you can use to break it down more.

I also want to throw out you can never trust IE9 to support any specific CSS feature correctly.

Comment: border-collapse takes out the padding in between the table border and the cell borders. I tried it but didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you throw your HTML and CSS into jsfiddle, it will make troubleshooting simpler. Or at least add the HTML as well.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gd7u9/